# Google+ Firebase Invites iOS9

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-invites

Firebase integration document for G+ Invites  says:

```
FIRInvites *appInviteDialog = [FIRInvites inviteDialog];
 [appInviteDialog setInviteDelegate:self];
```

Object for `FIRInvites` gets created but the methods of this class cant be accessed. I'm getting the following error msg:

> error : No visible @interface for 'FIRInvites' declares the selector 'setInviteDelegate:'

Calling the method without creating the object doesn't fire the above error or warnings but calls the delegate method `inviteFinishedWithInvitations`:

```
[[FIRInvites inviteDialog] setInviteDelegate:self];
[[FIRInvites inviteDialog] setMessage:@"Hi"];
```

Instead I get new error as follows:

> Error Domain=com.google.gpp.invite Code=-497 "Cannot launch the Invite Widget because message is not set." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot launch the Invite Widget because message is not set.}

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution may work for your problem,

Try declaring your appInviteDialog object as follows:

**@property(strong, nonatomic) id appInviteDialog;**

And use the object as below:

**_appInviteDialog = [FIRInvites inviteDialog];
 [appInviteDialog setInviteDelegate:self];**